# How to trigger a thread to start working using semaphore?

Tags: threads, semaphore

How to trigger a thread to start working using semaphore?

I have find a lot of explanation about thread and semaphore but i still don't understand, any help please

Comment: Do you think this is Computer Science?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, _in **computer science**, a semaphore is a variable or abstract data type used to control access to a common resource by multiple processes in a concurrent system such as a multitasking operating system._

Comment: It's not true that everything related to programming is outside the realm of computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using semaphores or locks, you don't do anything else than *acquiring* the semaphore (resp. the lock), and then do what you want.  For example, if you want to use a lock, then you typically have two threads

```
# thread 1
lock.acquire()
# here is all the work for thread 1
lock.release()
```

and the other thread is completely identical:

```
# thread 2
lock.acquire()
# here is all the work for thread 2
lock.release()
```

Now, the *first* to obtain the `lock` gets to run the code first, and the other thread needs to wait until the `lock` is released.

Here's an example of a Python program that prints a series of `0`s and `1`s depending on the order of execution:

```
import time
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()
lst = []


def f1():
    for i in range(10):
        lock.acquire()
        lst.append("0")
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.1)


def f2():
    for i in range(10):
        lock.acquire()
        lst.append("1")
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.1)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=f1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=f2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()

print("".join(lst))
```

Feel free to run it in your own terminal.

(Note that I used `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()`, but the "correct" way is to use a context manager and use `with lock: ...`.)

See also:  [Lock, mutex, semaphore… what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332765/lock-mutex-semaphore-whats-the-difference/45567101#45567101)